# how to access value of array of string by assigning it to string?

Tags: c#

`excelFilesNames` is a array of `string` and there is more than 1 value in `excelFilesNames`.
While printing `oVariableName[2]` value it prints `"system.string"`. i want to print all values of `excelFilesNames` by assigning it to `oVariableName[2]`.

the code is below

```
Object[] oVariableName = new object[3]; 
oVariableName[2] = excelFilesNames;     
MessageBox.Show(oVariableName[2].ToString());
```

Comment: Why not just `MessageBox.Show(excelFilesNames[2]);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object[] oVariableName = new object[3]; 
oVariableName[2] = string.Join(",", excelFilesNames);     
MessageBox.Show(oVariableName[2]);
```

You don't need to use a `Object[]` though:

```
var fileNames = string.Join(",", excelFilesNames);
MessageBox.Show(fileNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `excelFilesNames` is an array of strings, iterate it with a `foreach`:

```
Object[] oVariableName = new object[3]; 
oVariableName[2] = excelFilesNames;  

foreach (string s in oVariableName[2])
{
   MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Note I'm not sure why you assign the `string[]` to an `object` field inside an `object[]`, but I'll assume for your question that it's whats needed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Since the contents of `oVariableName[2]` is known to be a `string[]`, you can cast it to `string[]` and make use of `string.Join()` to create a multiline string with one line per filename, like so:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", (string[])oVariableName[2]));
```

However this will explode at runtime if `oVariableName[2]` is not an array of strings. You could protect against like that:

```
var asStringArray = oVariableName[2] as string[];

if (asStringArray != null)
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", asStringArray));
```

I don't really understand why you're using an array of objects in this way, but I guess there's some background that you haven't told us about.

Answer (score 0):

excelfileNames is array of string, so when your assigning to the oVariableName[2]
you should assign a specific value of it, rather assigning the whole object.

something like  below code.

```
    string [] excelFilesNames = new string[]{ "One","Two"};
    Object[] oVariableName = new object[3]; 
    oVariableName[2] = excelFilesNames[1];     
    MessageBox.Show(oVariableName[2].ToString());
```

Comment: but my need is to assign whole object value and not a specific value. well i got my answer, thank you for your precious time.